# Linking Backbone.js external files

Tags: backbone.js

I'm learning Backbonejs and I'm really confused with linking external JS files. So, if I write Backbone script in HTML document between  everything works fine. But if I add a link in HTML to JS file it doesn't work. I have tested jQuery in this file and it works fine, it seems like only Backbone.js scripts doesn't work. So, the main question is:

How do I link external JS files where I'm using Backbone.js to my HTML file?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js"></script>
        <script src="testingscript.js"></script>
        <title>Backbone for beginners</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="container">Loading...</div>

        <script>

        var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $('#container'),
            // template which has the placeholder 'who' to be substitute later
            template: _.template('<h3>Hello <%= who %></h3>'),
            initialize: function () {
                this.render();
            },
            render: function () {
                // render the function using substituting the varibile 'who' for 'world'
                this.$el.html(this.template({who: 'world!'})); 
            }
        });

            var appView = new AppView ();

        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Greetings!

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your HTML. You load Backbone and JS code that makes use of it the same way you load jQuery and code that makes use of it.

Comment: Can't be answered without any code. However, you will want to use a loader like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) instead of hardcoding script tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special magic to load other js files in the same HTML file that backbonejs is used.

I would make sure that your 'testingscript.js' file is in the right path and get loaded properly.  You can look at the console in your web-browser (From FireBug if you use fireFox, or 'Inspect Element' if Chome is used).

Once you confirm that the file is loaded properly, things should work as I don't see you have any unusual in your code.

Good luck!

```
<script src="testingscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh yes, I had files in different maps and the reference was not correct. Thanks, it works now!